# Raid 10 - 6 Disk - Dell MD3200

Tags: raid, storage, dell

I have 6 disk of 600GB.

I'm using a Dell Storage MD3200 , where i have created a disk group ( RAID 10 ) with 6 disks.

My disk slots parity are like this:

SLOT 1 : 0 
SLOT 4 : 1 
SLOT 7 : EMPTY 
SLOT 10 : EMPTY 
SLOT 2 : 1 
SLOT 5 : 0 
SLOT 8 : EMPTY 
SLOT 11 : EMPTY 
SLOT 3 : 0 
SLOT 6 : 1 
SLOT 9 : EMPTY 
SLOT 12 : EMPTY

How many slots could go down before my disk group goes down?

Thanks, sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two - if you lost both disks of a mirrored pair then you'd lose the whole array.

The MD3200 is technically RAID 01 - as it stripes data across multiple mirrored pairs.

Anyway yeah, two disks could take down your array - obviously you'd have to be unlucky to lose two in a pair but it does happen - this is why we backup :)

Comment: thanks chooper3 , have a nice day .